# Parse all integers from string in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem how to get all integer values from string in Objective-C

```
NSString *numbers = @"1, 2";
int number = [numbers intValue];
```

But this just takes the first number (1) but I need both of them.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSArray *listOfNumbers = [numbers componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *numberAsString in listOfNumbers) {
    int number = [numberAsString intValue];  // you might want to trim the string first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for if they're always separated by a ", ":

```
NSString *numbers = @"1, 2";
NSArray *numberTokens = [numbers componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
for (NSString *token in numberTokens) {
    NSLog(@"%i", token.integerValue);
}
```

This solution allows you to specify multiple characters that might separate the numbers:

```
NSString *numbers = @"1, 2";
NSArray *numberTokens = [numbers componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@", "]];
for (NSString *token in numberTokens) {
    if (token.length > 0) {
        NSLog(@"%@: %i", token, token.integerValue);
    }
}
```